# Django loop over all m2m relations

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I need to loop over all m2m relations of the model instance and copy them to new model instance.

```
source_id=request.GET.get('source_id', 1)
obj = Artist.objects.create(title='New artist')
source_obj = Artist.objects.get(id=source_id)
if source_obj.galleries.count():
   obj.galleries = source_obj.galleries.all()
if source_obj.suggested_artists.count():
   obj.suggested_artists = source_obj.suggested_artists.all()
```

Currently i am doing it like this, but i want to loop over all m2m fields and copy the related data to `obj`.

I want something like:

```
for m2m_rel in source_obj.m2m_relations:
    print geattr(source_obj, m2m_rel).count()
    print geattr(source_obj, m2m_rel).all()
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the m2m relation entries like this:

```
for field in source_obj._meta.many_to_many:
    source = getattr(source_obj, field.attname)
    for item in source.all():
        # do something with item...
        print repr(item)
```

If you're trying to clone a model intance, you can use a generic *clone_objects* function like the one below. The function will clone a list of objects and return a new list of cloned objects (with new ID's):

```
# import Python's copy library
import copy

def clone_objects(objects):
    """
    Generic model object cloner function.
    """
    def clone(obj):
        """Return an identical copy of the instance with a new ID."""
        if not obj.pk:
            raise ValueError('Instance must be saved before it can be cloned.')
        duplicate = copy.copy(obj)
        # Setting pk to None tricks Django into thinking this is a new object.
        duplicate.pk = None
        duplicate.save()
        # ... but the trick loses all ManyToMany relations.
        for field in obj._meta.many_to_many:
            source = getattr(obj, field.attname)
            destination = getattr(duplicate, field.attname)
            for item in source.all():
                destination.add(item)
        return duplicate

    if not hasattr(objects,'__iter__'):
        objects = [ objects ]

    objs = []
    for obj in objects:
        new_obj = clone(obj)
        new_obj.save()
        objs.append(new_obj)

    return objs
```

The main part of the "cloning" code is from this snippet: [Clone model mixin](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1271/)

Comment: The `clone_objects()` function above does not deal with e.g. `OneToOneField` relations. Moreover, in some cases a `deepcopy` may be required instead of a shallow one. I would not call this "generic." See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#copying-model-instances).